# Handle exception in Html.BeginForm MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form in a view that is marked with @html.beginForm. This form consists of dropdowns, text boxes and a button. The drop downs are populated dynamically through ajax call. ie. selection of one value from the drop down triggers an ajax call and dynamically populates all the drop down boxes.

This form has a button to post and bring up another form. The problem that I am having is that when an exception happens in the controller, how do i show the error message to the user and preserve the form values filled out by the user?

Here is my view:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="panel panel-default animated zoomInDown" style="padding-top:25px">
    <div class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" id="dashSpinner" style="display:none;text-align:center;"></div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "MyEntities", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createEntityForm" }))
    {
       /*Form consists of dropdowns and text boxes*/
    }
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = Entities)]  EntityModel model)
    {
        try
        {
                //If everything goes well, redirect to another form
                return RedirectToAction("AnotherForm", "Event", new { id = eventid });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Catch exception and show it to the user?
            log.Error(e);
            model.Error = e.Message;
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is my ajax call to show error message to the user

```
    $("#createEntityForm").on("submit", function (e) {
        $("#dashSpinner").show();
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            //success: function (response) {
            //    debugger;
            //},
            error: function (response) {
                debugger;

                $("#dashSpinner").hide();
                swal({
                    title: "Error",
                    text: "You cannot take this type of action on this event.",
                    type: "error",
                    showConfirmButton: true
                });
            }                
        });


        $("#dashSpinner").hide();
    });
```

Comment: Where is your code and put your error message.

Comment: First, your making an ajax call, and ajax call never redirect, so having a `return RedirectToAction()` in your controller method makes no sense. Second, you catching the error in your controller, and just returning a valid response, so your `error:` function will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery.ajax error callback is executed when server response has status code different than 200.

You should return response using `HttpStatusCodeResult` ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpstatuscoderesult)) or setting `Response.StatusCode` ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx)) in catch block.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that triggers the Error event is getting a non 2xx status code.

Alter your ActionMethod to use a non-2xx status code. You can do this by using `Response.StatusCode = 500;`.

You are also always returning a view - if you want to show just an error message it may be easier to return a `JsonResult` and then update your error handling to just show this error. In that case your ActionMethod catch statement could become:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
  log.Error(e);
  Response.StatusCode = 500;
  Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
  return Json(new { message = e.Message } );
}
```

You then need to update your JQuery error handler to show the message as currently it will always show the same error ("You cannot take this type of action on this event."). To do this you need to output the message sent as part of the JSON payload.

```
error: function (response) {
    $("#dashSpinner").hide();
    swal({
        title: "Error",
        text: response.responseJSON.message,
        type: "error",
        showConfirmButton: true
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the Controller

```
     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = Entities)]  EntityModel model)
    {
      //If something goes wrong return to the form with the errors.

      if(!ModelState.isValid()) return Create(model);


       //If everything goes well, redirect to another form
         return RedirectToAction("AnotherForm", "Event", new { id = 


      return View(model);
    }
```

You can check too unobtrusive for jquery at the client side. https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-unobtrusive-validation/